# Exercise on relative constructibility

Tags: set-theory

Given a set $A$ in Kunen's set theory book (page 143) we can find the following definition of the relative constructible universe $L[A]$.

- $L[A](0)=\{A\}\cup \operatorname{tr cl}(A)$
- $L[A](\alpha+1)=\mathcal{D}^+(L[A](\alpha))$
- $L[A](\gamma)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} L[A](\alpha)$ if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.

where $trcl(A)$ denotes the transitive closure of $A$ and $\mathcal{D}^+(L[A](\alpha))$ the collection of all sets defined with parameters in $L[A](\alpha)$.

In this regard, it is known that if $A\subset \omega$ then $L[A]$ satisfies $GCH$. So my question is, if $A\subset \omega$ then does $L[A]$ satisfy $V=L$ and $AC$ and therefore $GCH$ is true in $L[A]$?

Every answer or correction will be appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $A\subset \omega$ is a nonconstructible "real", such as, oh, $0^\sharp$.

Comment: I'm disappointed by the confusion of $L(A)$ and $L[A]$. Is this the new book?

Comment: @Asaf It is the 2013, revised edition. He defined $L[A]$ exactly as OP did, so he writes $L[A](\alpha)$ for what usually is known as $L_\alpha(A)$ - a rather unfortunate choice of notation, I think.

Answer (score 3):

There are two notions of relative constructibility, $L[A]$ and $L(A)$. What you describe is actually $L(A)$ and not $L[A]$, and the two coincide when $A$ is a subset of $L$ (e.g. a set of ordinals).

In the $L[A]$ construction we add $A$ as a predicate to the language and we construct the model by starting with the empty set, and taking the definable (with parameters) subsets of the structure $(L_\alpha[A],\in,A\cap L_\alpha[A])$.

You can prove that $L[A]$ is always a model of $\sf ZFC$, whereas $L(A)$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$ if and only if the transitive closure of $\{A\}$ has a definable well-ordering (so in most cases, choice fails in $L(A)$).

To make matters worse, a lot of people confuse the two notations often, or simply don't care enough to discern them. But there is a significant difference between $L[\Bbb R]$ and $L(\Bbb R)$ in certain contexts.

But as I said, if $A$ is a set of ordinals, then the two things are the same so there's no room for confusion. Now to your question.

It is certainly not true that $L[A]\models V=L$, this will be true if $A\in L$, but if $A$ is not constructible itself, then this is no longer true. The proof, however, is somewhat similar to the proof that $\sf GCH$ holds in $L$. You can even show that if $A\subseteq\omega_1$ then $\sf GCH$ holds in $L[A]$.

It need not be true for a subset of $\omega_2$ since we can force over $L$ to add $\aleph_2$ generic reals and code them as a subset $A$ of $\omega_2$, so $L[A]\models 2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ in that case.

Comment: OP may be interested in the following: Letting $A^* = A \cap L[A]$ we have $L[A] = L[A^*] = L(A^*)$, $A^* \in L[A^*]$ and $L[A^*] \models "V = L[A^*]"$, where $V = L[A^*]$ is $\Pi_2$ in the parameter $A^*$. (It's the obvious generalization of the usual $"V =L"$ sentence.) Furthermore, for any set $X$ there is a set $A \subseteq \operatorname{Ord}$ such that $X \in L[A]$. As a consequence of this, $\operatorname{GCH}$ may fail anywhere in $L[A]$ (but it never fails everywhere, i.e. on a tail segment, we always have $\operatorname{GCH}$).

Comment: @Asaf I'm so sorry but I'm completely stuck trying to prove that $L[A]\vDash GCH$...

Comment: @Ergonvi: Do you know the proof that GCH holds in L?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, it needs the Gödel's condensation. Is there some similar result which can be applied to elementary substructures of $L_\alpha(A)$?

Comment: Yes, you can find it in Jech in the chapter about constructibility.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you very much. Regarding $L[A]$ what does the definable subsets of the structure $(L_\alpha[A],\in, A\cap L_\alpha[A])$ mean? How does $A\cap L_\alpha[A]$ defined?

Comment: @Ergonvi: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. $A$ is a set, or a class, and $L_\alpha[A]$ is a set. Then the intersection is a set. Now you have a structure of a language which has a binary relation $\in$ and a predicate $A$ interpreted as the set $A\cap L_\alpha[A]$. Now you ask what sort of sets are definable in this structure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was trying to ask how the elements of $L_{\alpha+1}[A]$ looks like. Do we bild up them using as a parameters elements from $L_\alpha[A]$ and from $A\cap L_\alpha[A]$?

Comment: @Ergonvi: It's the same construction as you do in $L$, only your language has another predicate.