# On Kunen's Set Theory, Exercise II.6.30

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

We define the relative constructible sets, $L[A](\delta)$ as follows:

1. $L[A](0)=\{A\}\cup \operatorname{trcl}(A)$
2. $L[A](\beta+1)=\mathcal{D}^+(L[A](\beta))$
3. $L[A](\gamma)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma} L[A](\alpha)$ for limit ordinals $\gamma$.

and $L[A] = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbf{ON}}L[A](\alpha)$. Note that as mentioned by Asaf [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671672/exercise-on-relative-constructibility?rq=1), the conventional notation for this definition should be $L(A)$ instead (for the context of this question, I will stick to $L[A]$).

Exercise II.6.30 afterwards then states that:

> For any $A$, $L[A]$ is a transitive model of $\mathsf{ZF}$, and $A \in L[A]$. Also, $L[A] \models \mathsf{AC}$ if $A$ is a set of ordinals, and $L[A] \models \mathsf{GCH}$ if $A \subseteq \omega$.

Both transitivity and $A \in L[A]$ are clear, but I'm not certain about the last two parts. For $\mathsf{AC}$, I have not worked out the details, but I think this follows from that $L[A](0)$ is a well-orderable set. Then the proof of which $L[A] \models \mathsf{AC}$ should follow similarly to that of the original $L \models \mathsf{AC}$. Unfortunately for $L[A] \models \mathsf{GCH}$, I don't have much idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $L[A]$ satisfies the (appropriate form of the) condensation lemma?

Comment: Your remark for the AC part is on the right track but misses an important detail. For instance, even if $V$ satisfies AC, $L(A)$ does not necessarily satisfy AC, so it isn't as simple as saying $L_0(A)$ is well-orderable. However, if there is a *definable* well-ordering of $L_0(A)$ (which there is in this case) then that is enough for the same proof to go through as for $L$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber apologies for the delayed response. It appears that Kunen's book does  not mention the condensation lemma. Do you have a text recommended for me to refer to on this matter?